# Login on password prompt in linux through perl script

Tags: linux, perl, scripting, terminal, login-script

I want to pass a password through a Perl script. I am basically writing a script to execute commands on Linux terminal.

At a particular commands execution, I get a prompt for

```
Password :← (I need to enter password here through my script)
```

But, my script just stops working.

After browsing, I found `Expect` but I get an error saying: `Can't locate Expect.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .)`

I have not used `Expect` before so have no clue what do I need to install.

Comment: How are you accessing the Linux system?

Answer (score 3):

[Expect.pm should work on Windows](https://metacpan.org/module/Expect.pm#Can-I-use-this-module-with-ActivePerl-on-Windows-) with latest [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com).

If I am correct you could install expect with PPM. However, it seems to me that it may not work: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Expect/

It looks like [IO-Tty](https://metacpan.org/release/IO-Tty) fails to install on Windows. It should work on Cygwin.