# How to enter/answer a terminal prompt from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, terminal, prompt, interactive, non-interactive

I'm trying to crack a forgotten password for a luks partition. I generated a list of combinations, and now I'm trying to decrypt the volume from a Perl script.

The problem is to enter the prompt from the script itself, since: `system('cryptsetup', ('open', '/dev/sdd1', 'crypt-vol', '--type=luks'))` just spits `Enter passphrase for /dev/sdd1` and waits for me to enter it manually.

How can I approach this?

Many thankyous for any help.

* *it's my volume and I haven't forgotten the password completely, so I created the list of combinations provided that I remember some details. It's like >6k of possibilities, so it should be feasible to break it.*

Comment: Is this the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236307/login-on-password-prompt-in-linux-through-perl-script

Comment: Forget perl. Use `expect` which is designed to deal with interactive programs reading from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Use the Perl module [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RGIERSIG/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) perhaps?

Comment: @Jens I already created something with the Perl Expect module. Seems to run, now I'll wait for about 20 hours at max (my estimate), then depending on the results I'll post something, either an answer (if it works) or update the question.

Comment: @TLP yes, I'm doing it now. The only possible? problem may be that I create a new expect instance in each while loop, since `crypsetup` exits with code 512 on the second or 3rd atemt to enter a password

Comment: @user907860 That might be something you could ask about in a new question

Comment: reading the man page for cryptsetup, you can specify --key-file instead of a password prompt

Comment: `--key-file` can be STDIN too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't, use a 'keyfile' with cryptsetup. A key file can be STDIN.

So:

```
echo "passphrase_here" | cryptsetup -d - <other  options>
```

In perl you could use `IPC::Run2` for this, which allows you read/write to the FH, but if you just need a return code to test the passphrase, that's not needed.

E.g. https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/03/27/how-to-test-luks-passphrase/

So:

```
open ( my $crypter, '|-', "cryptsetup luksOpen -d - --test-passphrase " )

print {$crypter} "Your passphrase";

close ( $crypter );
print "Got return code of $?"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I actually liked the idea to use STDIN, so if anyone ever lights upon this page, consider if you can use STDIN in your situation.**

But I'd like to post my own answer, which uses the Expect Perl module, because:

- I used it and it's proven to work at least on Linux (though the question in the comments mentions that the module had problems to run on Windows);
- since the question was titled without any mention of `cryptsetup` (which can accept the password on STDIN), so the Expect module is like a general solution here, which should work for other tools;

My solution is below. I didn't read the documentation much, so there may be better ways to do this. For me it was enough to grasp the idea of the object instantiation, and the expect/send methods.

You create an instance as if you just started a program in the terminal:

```
my $exp = Expect->new('progName', ($arg1, $arg2, $etc));
```

Then it's possible to interact with it through the `expect` (which waits/confirms the program's output to the user) and `send` (which allows the user to 'type') methods.

`expect` may be called in either scalar or list context (I used the list one) and it accepts a string or regexp of what output to expect and for how long. If no expected output occurred within the specified time it throws an error:

```
                       #sec to wait for  #use regexp (don't match exactly) #regexp to match against
my @out = $exp->expect(10,               '-re',                            'smth');
```

`send` just accepts the input

```
$exp->send('some chars');
```

**That's it, one just need to create a script, which would work as if it was a human user.**

---

And just in case it might be handy to someone, I'll post my complete particular solution for cryptsetup (I've tested it on a dummy volume, which it was able to mount, and I've run it on a real volume with 6k combinations tried without any noticeable problems):

*I forgot to close the file descriptor here, so one should add `close($fd)` where appropriate

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';


# I installed Expect with its deps locally in my situation, so I had to change @INC
BEGIN {
  unshift(@INC, './perl-mods/lib/perl5/');
  unshift(@INC, './perl-mods/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/');
}

use Expect;

my $devName = '/dev/sdb3';
my $combinationsFileName = 'combs.txt';
open(my $fd, '<', $combinationsFileName);
my $lineCount = 0;

while (<$fd>) {
  my $pass = $_;
  chomp($_);
  say $_ . ' ' . ++$lineCount;

  my $exp = Expect->new('cryptsetup', ('open', $devName, 'crypt-vol')) or die 'err 1';
  my @out = $exp->expect(10, '-re', 'Enter passphrase') or die 'err 2';
  $exp->send($pass);
  @out = $exp->expect(10, '-re', 'No key available') or die 'err 3';

  #if cryptsetup returned an error code
  if ($out[1]) {
    die $out[1] . ' ' . $pass;
  }
}
```